# labeling based on the character value of numerical variables for bar chart based on bins

Tags: r, label

I am making chart based on bins from the data for range of values of x. I am looking, if the labels of bins values(range of x values) can be replaced into characters from xtype ( from extremely saline to non saline) made from x.
thanks

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Seed(123)
ID = 1:5
Time = rep (c(1,2,3,4,5), each = 20)
Type = 1:25
data <- data.frame( IDn = rep(ID,20), Time,  Land = rep(Type, 40), y = rnorm(100,0,1), x = runif(100,0,1))
data$Land= ifelse (data$Land > 15,"large farmers", ifelse(data$Land <=5, "small farmers", "medium-farmers"))
data<- data %>% mutate(xtype = case_when(x> 0.8~ 'Extremely Saline',
                                                      x > 0.6 & x<=0.8~  'Severely Saline',
                                                      x > 0.5 & x<=0.6~ 'Highly Saline',
                                                     x > 0.3 & x<=0.5~ 'Moderatley Saline',
                                                      x > 0.2 & x<=0.3~ 'Slightly Saline',
                                                      x <= 0.2~ 'Non saline' ))
data %>%
  group_by(Time, Land) %>%
  mutate(x = cut(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(Time, Land, x) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Time, n, fill = Land) + geom_col(position = 'dodge') + facet_grid(Land~x)
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` and `cut` are alternatives here, don't use both at the same time.

If you have already used `case_when` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  count(Time, Land, xtype) %>%
  mutate(xtype = factor(xtype, c('Non saline', 'Slightly Saline', 
                        'Moderatley Saline','Highly Saline', 'Severely Saline',
                        'Extremely Saline'))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Time, n, fill = Land) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  facet_grid(Land~xtype)
```

[image]

---

With `cut` assign `labels` to `breaks` -

```
data %>%
  group_by(Time, Land) %>%
  mutate(x = cut(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1), 
                 labels = c('Non saline', 'Slightly Saline', 'Moderatley Saline',
                    'Highly Saline', 'Severely Saline','Extremely Saline'))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(Time, Land, x) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Time, n, fill = Land) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + facet_grid(Land~x)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak. it is working, but the order of the values is disturbed in the chart. can it be fixed as written in the codes from non saline to extremely saline?

Comment: We can adjust the order of plotting by using factor. See the updated answer.